# Number of squares in a grid under certain conditions

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-sequences

Consider an $(n+1)\times (n+1)$ grid of lattice points in the plane.

$A(n):$ # of squares with vertices on the grid.

It's relatively well-known that $A(n)=\frac{n(n+1)^2(n+2)}{12}$. Now, $A(n)  = B(n) + C(n)$ .
Where $B(n) = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ is the number of "orthogonal" squares. Meaning that
the sides are parallel to borders of original square.

$C(n):$ # of "slanted" squares.

$C(n) = D(n) + E(n)$ . Where,

$D(n):$ # of squares intersecting the sides of unit squares.

$E(n):$ # of squares non-intersecting the sides of unit squares.

**My question is to find a closed formula for $E(n)$.**

Note that $D(n) + E(n) = \frac{n^4 - n^2}{12}$. Hence
$$
D(1) = 0,  D(2) = 0, D(3) = 2, D(4) = 10, D(5) = 30, D(6) = 73, D(7) = 148\\
E(1) = 0, E(2) = 1, E(3) = 4, E(4) = 10, E(5) = 20, E(6) = 32, E(7) = 48 
$$
Maybe $E(n) = A008050$ in *OEIS*.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but what is your question? Your post looks like a statement. Do you mean to ask if $E(n)$ is given by A008050 in OEIS? Also, do you have a reason to believe that this is the case, other than having the first few numbers correct?

Comment: My question is to find a closed formula for $E(n)$. (in bold). I'm not sure that coincide with A008050, the only evidence are the first few values.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to make it clear what you are asking and what are your own thoughts. It didn't even cross my mind that you were after a formula for $E(n)$. The meaning of the word "find" is a bit unclear. By the way, are you familiar with the site http://math.stackexchange.com/ and the difference between it and MathOverflow?

Comment: Is it not the case that the squares counted by $E(n)$ are precisely the squares rotated $\pi/4$ from the orthogonal? If so, they should be fairly easy to count and I'd think it wouldn't be hard to find a formula.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I don't think so. In $E(n)$ we have squares with side-length $\sqrt{2}$ (for example).

Comment: Yes, and the sides of those squares are rotated through $\pi/4$ with respect to the borders of the original square. Aren't all of the $E(n)$ squares like that?

Comment: I think that in $E(n)$ we have squares with side-lengths $\sqrt{2}, 2\sqrt{2}, 3\sqrt{2}, ... , \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\sqrt{2}$. A good idea could be how many of each kind.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what you mean by **intersecting the sides of unit squares** but based on your comment I think it is just what Gerry says: Your grid makes up $n^2$ unit squares and $E(n)$ counts the squares of side $\sqrt{2}, 2\sqrt{2}, 3\sqrt{2}, ... , \lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor\sqrt{2}$ whose sides have slope $\pm 1.$ The number of these is $(n-1)^2+(n-3)^2+\cdots$ which agrees with $3^2+1^2=10=E(4)$ and $4^2+2^2=20=E(5)$ but would suggest $5^2+3^2+1^2=35$ for $E(6).$ Are you sure your counts are correct? If it is what Gerry says then $E(n)=\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{6}.$

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. $E(6)$ and $E(7)$ must be fixed. We have $E(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}(n+1-2k)^2 = \frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{6}$.